# FirebaseCrashlytics SDK Android установка

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase

Я переписываю приложение, и решил заменить Crashlytics на FirebaseCrashlytics SDK

Выполнил все действия в

```
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?hl=ru&platform=android
```

При запуске приложение падает с ошибкой

```
2020-05-07 21:43:01.288 6597-6597/com.app.peshkariki E/FirebaseCrashlytics: .
2020-05-07 21:43:01.289 6597-6597/com.app.peshkariki E/FirebaseCrashlytics: .     |  | 
2020-05-07 21:43:01.289 6597-6597/com.app.peshkariki E/FirebaseCrashlytics: .     |  |
2020-05-07 21:43:01.289 6597-6597/com.app.peshkariki E/FirebaseCrashlytics: .     |  |
2020-05-07 21:43:01.289 6597-6597/com.app.peshkariki E/FirebaseCrashlytics: .   \ |  | /
2020-05-07 21:43:01.289 6597-6597/com.app.peshkariki E/FirebaseCrashlytics: .    \    /
2020-05-07 21:43:01.289 6597-6597/com.app.peshkariki E/FirebaseCrashlytics: .     \  /
2020-05-07 21:43:01.289 6597-6597/com.app.peshkariki E/FirebaseCrashlytics: .      \/
2020-05-07 21:43:01.289 6597-6597/com.app.peshkariki E/FirebaseCrashlytics: .
2020-05-07 21:43:01.289 6597-6597/com.app.peshkariki E/FirebaseCrashlytics: The Crashlytics build ID is missing. This occurs when Crashlytics tooling is absent from your app's build configuration. Please review Crashlytics onboarding instructions and ensure you have a valid Crashlytics account.
2020-05-07 21:43:01.289 6597-6597/com.app.peshkariki E/FirebaseCrashlytics: .
2020-05-07 21:43:01.289 6597-6597/com.app.peshkariki E/FirebaseCrashlytics: .      /\
2020-05-07 21:43:01.289 6597-6597/com.app.peshkariki E/FirebaseCrashlytics: .     /  \
2020-05-07 21:43:01.289 6597-6597/com.app.peshkariki E/FirebaseCrashlytics: .    /    \
2020-05-07 21:43:01.289 6597-6597/com.app.peshkariki E/FirebaseCrashlytics: .   / |  | \
2020-05-07 21:43:01.289 6597-6597/com.app.peshkariki E/FirebaseCrashlytics: .     |  |
2020-05-07 21:43:01.289 6597-6597/com.app.peshkariki I/chatty: uid=10080(com.app.peshkariki) identical 1 line
2020-05-07 21:43:01.289 6597-6597/com.app.peshkariki E/FirebaseCrashlytics: .     |  |
2020-05-07 21:43:01.289 6597-6597/com.app.peshkariki E/FirebaseCrashlytics: .
2020-05-07 21:43:01.294 6597-6597/com.app.peshkariki D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-05-07 21:43:01.305 6597-6597/com.app.peshkariki E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.app.peshkariki, PID: 6597
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Crashlytics build ID is missing. This occurs when Crashlytics tooling is absent from your app's build configuration. Please review Crashlytics onboarding instructions and ensure you have a valid Crashlytics account.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6242)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5805)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5722)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Crashlytics build ID is missing. This occurs when Crashlytics tooling is absent from your app's build configuration. Please review Crashlytics onboarding instructions and ensure you have a valid Crashlytics account.
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.c.g.k.n(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0:136)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.b.b(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0:78)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.CrashlyticsRegistrar.b(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0:55)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.CrashlyticsRegistrar.a(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.a.a(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.firebase.components.l.f(com.google.firebase:firebase-components@@16.0.0:69)
        at com.google.firebase.components.i.get(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.firebase.components.q.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-components@@16.0.0:53)
        at com.google.firebase.components.l.e(com.google.firebase:firebase-components@@16.0.0:158)
        at com.google.firebase.c.l(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:563)
        at com.google.firebase.c.o(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:304)
        at com.google.firebase.c.n(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:268)
        at com.google.firebase.c.m(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:253)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:51)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1917)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1892)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:45)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6239)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5805) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5722) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Раньше использовался код

```
Crashlytics.setUserIdentifier(user.id)
```

Сейчас `Crashlytics.setUserId(user.id)`

где этот объект представляет собой

```
object Crashlytics {
    fun log(e: Error){
        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log(e.printStackTrace().toString())
        Log.d("Error даня", e.printStackTrace().toString())
    }
    fun log(e: Exception){
        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log(e.printStackTrace().toString())
        Log.d("Exception даня2", e.printStackTrace().toString())
    }

    fun log(message: String){
        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log(message)
        Log.d("Exception даня3", message)
    }

    fun setUserId(id: String){
        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setUserId(id)
    }

}
```

Что еще не хватает?

**gradle project**

```
uildscript {
    ext.nav_version = '1.0.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven/" }
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0-alpha08'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.72"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.0.0'
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven/" }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**gradle module**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 346
        versionName "3.2.0"

        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.incremental":"true"]
            }
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }

    buildTypes.each {
        it.buildConfigField 'String', 'appMetrica', appMetrica
    }

    buildFeatures{
//        viewBinding = false //новая хуйня, лучше чем синтетика (вроде)

        dataBinding = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }


}

dependencies {

    //Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы забыли добавить

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```